# CType Operator, assing to member

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this class:

```
Public Class Foo

    Public X As Integer
    Public Y As Integer
    Public Value As String

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(v As String) As Foo
        Dim fobj As New Foo
        fobj.Value = v
        Return fobj
    End Operator

End Class
```

And this Code:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim f As New Foo
    f.X = 3
    f.Y = 10
    f = "Bar"
End Sub
```

In the f = "Bar" assignment I loose the previous X and Y values previously assigned.
There's a way to overload the operator to assign to the "Value" member instead of creating a new Foo class? Or a way to obtain the target of the assignment to copy the values??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No; that's totally impossible.

Comment: Also confusing and wrong. But if you're determined to be mean, you can overload another operator, say, `&`, and make it do it.

Comment: Maybe wrong, but believe me, it could be very very useful for me.

Comment: I think the term assing is fitting ;)

Comment: My english is terrible... Sorry :$

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest you can get:

```
Public Shared Operator &(ByVal x As Foo, ByVal y As String) As Foo
    x.Value = y
    Return x
End Operator
```

```
f.X = 3
f.Y = 10
f &= "Bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it going to override its return a new instance of Foo which you're instructing to put in variable f, which did contain the previous Foo.

I think it would be better to define a Constructor (Eg NEW).

```
Public Class Foo
 Public Property Value() As String
 Public Property X() As Integer
 Public Property Y() As Integer

 Public Sub New()
 End Sub

 Public Sub New(ByVal Value As String, x As Integer, y As Integer)
  Value = Value
  x = x
  y = y
 End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can simply write

```
Dim f0 = New Foo("ABC", 1, 2)
Dim f1 = New Foo() With {.Value = "ABC", .X = 1, .Y = 2}
```